# JS Regex Negated Lookahead - Finding 2 Consecutive Dots

Tags: javascript, regex

Using a negated lookahead, I'm trying to test for two consecutive dots - but it isn't working. Can anyone explain why the following returns true?

```
/\.(?!\.)/.test('3..14')
```

Comment: Because in subject string there is a period which isn't following another one.

Comment: yes there is "3..14"

Comment: `'3..14'.match(/\.(?!\.)/)` returns the second dot. As @revo said, the second dot does not fail the test becaues it doesn't have a dot in front of it.

Comment: @jzisme the second `dot` is followed by `1` instead of `.` so you're condition evaluates to true

Answer (score 1):

`/^(?!.*?\.\.).*?$/` will match anything that doesn't contain consecutive dots and return the whole match if you need it.

[Regex Pal tests](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97368).